# How do I get a worksheet to always start in a certain place when opened?

Tags: excel

I have a GANTT chart (organisational worksheet) and because I have so much in it I always have to scroll for miles to the right before I get to the current day. I can't delete all the old stuff so I was wondering if there was a way I could get it to open on a certain section of the worksheet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe worksheet_activate with goto or select? maybe just hide what you don't want to see?

Comment: FYI: Jeeped is referring to VBA, you can't really do it any other way :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it assumes the dates are headers in row 1:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        For Each col In Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns
            If col.Cells(1, 1).Value = [Today()] Then
                col.Cells(1, 1).Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```